# How do I hook into TransactionScope on completing "event"?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, transactionscope, masstransit

I want to know if there's a way to hook into a currently running transaction and have stuff be done when that transaction completes.

Currently I'm in the process of implementing an `EventPublisher` that uses MassTransit/RabbitMQ to publish messages, but I want to only have those messages be published when a TransactionScope is getting completed.

I would check inside the `EventPublisher.PublishEvent()` method if there's currently a transaction running, if no, then fire off the messages, if yes, then collect the messages and wait for the transaction to complete to send them off.

```
var ep = container.GetInstance<IEventPublisher>();

using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  ... do some stuff 
  SaveEntity(entity);
  ep.PublishEvent(new EntitySaved(entity.Id));

  ... do some more stuff ...

  UpdateEntity(differentEntity);
  ep.PublishEvent(new EntityUpdated(differentEntity.Id));

  ... do even more stuff ...

  ep.PublishEvent(new UnrelatedMessage(someData));

  scope.Complete(); // <- only want the actual sending off to RabbitMQ to happen here.
}
```

I found this `TransactionCompleted` Event here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted 
But it seems to only be fired after the `scope.Complete()` bits are over and done.

I could use this to check if the transaction status is completed and then like actually fire off those messages I collected during the transaction. But my problem is that the connection to RabbitMQ could be down. And then I wouldn't be able to send those messages, but all the work above has been done already, but I never was able to send off those messages.

What I actually want is to somehow hook into the bit where the transaction is currently completing and during that process I fire off my messages and if that fails I can throw an exception and have that still running transaction go out the window.

Maybe there's a way to do that with MassTransit, but the documentation isn't really forthcoming there.

Here's some example code showing the problem.

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

            var sql = @"insert into [SomeTable] (
                [Id]
                ,[Name]
                ,[Index]
                ,[RelationId]
                ) values (@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4) ";

            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += CurrentOnTransactionCompleted;
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.NewGuid();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = "Blah";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param3", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = 1;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param4", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Parse("a401866d-3bdd-48a4-a78b-d40864c8471b");
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }

        private static void CurrentOnTransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
        {
            // I want to do stuff here but if this stuff fails I need the whole transaction to roll back.
            ... do some stuff that can fail ...

            e.Transaction.Rollback(new Exception("Bad transaction!"));

            // or
            throw new Exception("Bad transaction!"); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe the outbox feature does what you need and it has nothing to do with transactions. It just collects all the messages that you want to send or publish and does it only if the message is successfully consumed https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#outbox

Comment: The thing is, I'm not inside a consumer here. All the message consumers are part of one or multiple dedicated other processes. This here is specifically only using MT to send messages to RabbitMQ. So no ReceiveEndpoint configured there.

Comment: Can't you use the Transaction.Rollback() method in case the RabbitMQ is down.... As in once in the TransactionCompleted event you check and find RabbitMQ is down you can call eventArg.Transaction.Rollback()

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. You get a `System.Transactions.TransactionException: 'The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.'` exception when trying to rollback the transaction from inside the event. Reason being that the transaction is already completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place. After looking through microsoft/referencesource I found what I was looking for in TransactionContext.cs.

What you need is to hook up an `IEnlistmentNotification` which is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transaction.enlistvolatile

I need to put my code inside the Prepare method and if it fails call `ForceRollback`.

Comment: So would it make sense to create a TransactionOutbox that would release the messages to the broker once the transaction is committed? Similar to InMemory, but triggered by the transaction.

Comment: Yes. Exactly that. I will be doing that myself, but I guess it would be cool if MassTransit would support that scenario ootb.

Comment: If you get it working and want to share the solution/code back to the project, that would be great.